# Origin of the background image of MyMonero

Tags: mymonero, history

How has the background image of MyMonero been choosen ? Is there a hidden reference ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to fluffypony](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=583449.msg16214438#msg16214438):

> it was just a stock image that looked cool:)